# Who is understood to be the "one like a man" referred to in Daniel 7:13?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, daniel-book-of

In Daniel 7, the Ancient of Days is identified.  I assume that this is referring to G-d Himself.  Then, "one like a man" approaches the Ancient of Days, and to this one is given "a dominion and glory and a kingdom" and all the world will serve him.  Indeed, his dominion will be "an eternal dominion".

> I saw in the visions of the night, and behold with the clouds of the heaven, **one like a man** was coming, and he came up to the Ancient of Days and was brought before Him.  And He gave him dominion and glory and a kingdom, and all peoples, nations, and tongues shall serve him; his dominion is an eternal dominion, which will not be removed, and his kingdom is one which will not be destroyed.  [Daniel 7:13-14](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16490#v=13)

What interpretations are given for who this "one like a man" is?

Comment: Hi Narnian, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for the question

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/25709/who-did-daniel-see

Comment: If you look at that link, but like this, Rashi says this is Moshiach: http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16490#showrashi=true&v=13

Comment: @Yishai Thank you.  I saw that, (after I finally saw the show/hide on the page), but was wondering if there were any more specific interpretations about this.  The Moshiach is a man, I presume, but it seems that what he receives is a pretty amazing gift.

Answer (score 3):

The "one like a man" is no one in particular: this is a dream. But whom does the dream allude to by that character? The messiah, according to the commentaries on that verse (*Rashi*, ibn Ezra, *M'tzudas David*) and as alluded to in the Talmud ([Sanhedrin 98:1](http://e-daf.com/index.asp?ID=3805)).

Answer (score 0):

The relevant passage in the Babylonian Talmud is *Sanhedrin* 11:1, I.100.A [Folio 98A], which references the passage of [Daniel 7:13](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/16490#v=13).

***Please click on this image to enlarge.***

[image: Meshiach]

To read the complete passage in context (in English), please click [**here**](http://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Sanhedrin.pdf) and read from Page 430 onward.

Comment: Hi Joseph and a belated welcome to Mi Yodeya.  I've noticed that you've included images from the talmud in several of your answers.  Are these from a digital source?  If so, would it be possible for you to cut and paste the text into your answers instead of just taking a screen shot? That way your answer would be accessible to people who have trouble with images (like people using screen-readers).  And it'd also add some Google juice to your answers.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Hello, Monica! I use [Logos6 software with the Jewish Studies Bundle XL](https://www.logos.com/product/46222/logos-6-jewish-studies-bundle-xl). The resource is INCREDIBLE for studying the Talmud, because you can search words or Bible verses with a mouse click. I can only do screen shots, but when possible, I try to link to some resources on the Internet.

Comment: Thanks for explaining what you're using.  I use a Soncino text bundle (also with a nice interface, including search) and I can cut/paste from that, which is why I asked.